# How to add a table to my SQLAlchemy query's FROM's?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to convert a working, large, complex SQL query to SQLAlchemy's ORM.

Here's a small example program that demonstrates the problem I'm seeing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""
An SSCCE.

Environment variables:
    DBU  Your database user
    DBP  Your database password
    DBH  Your database host
    IDB  Your initial database
"""

import os
import pprint

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased, sessionmaker, declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
Base = declarative_base()


class NV(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tb_nv"
    __bind_key__ = "testdb"
    __table_args__ = (
        {
            "mysql_engine": "InnoDB",
            "mysql_charset": "utf8",
            "mysql_collate": "utf8_general_ci",
        },
    )

    id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    builds = db.relationship("Bld", primaryjoin="(NV.id == Bld.variant_id)")


class Vers(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tb_vers"
    __bind_key__ = "testdb"
    __table_args__ = (
        {
            "mysql_engine": "InnoDB",
            "mysql_charset": "utf8",
            "mysql_collate": "utf8_general_ci",
        },
    )

    id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)


class St(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tb_brst"
    __bind_key__ = "testdb"
    __table_args__ = ({"mysql_engine": "InnoDB", "mysql_charset": "utf8"},)

    id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    version_id = db.Column(
        "version_id",
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey(
            "tb_vers.id",
            name="fk_tb_brst_version_id",
            onupdate="CASCADE",
            ondelete="RESTRICT",
        ),
        nullable=False,
    )
    branch_id = db.Column(
        "branch_id",
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey(
            "tb_br.id",
            name="fk_tb_brst_branch_id",
            onupdate="CASCADE",
            ondelete="RESTRICT",
        ),
        nullable=False,
    )
    build_id = db.Column(
        "build_id",
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey(
            "tb_bld.id",
            name="fk_tb_brst_build_id",
            onupdate="CASCADE",
            ondelete="RESTRICT",
        ),
        nullable=False,
    )

    version = db.relationship(
        "Vers", innerjoin=True, primaryjoin="(St.version_id == Vers.id)"
    )
    branch = db.relationship(
        "Br", innerjoin=True, primaryjoin="(St.branch_id == Br.id)"
    )
    build = db.relationship(
        "Bld", innerjoin=True, primaryjoin="(St.build_id == Bld.id)"
    )


class Br(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tb_br"
    __bind_key__ = "testdb"
    __table_args__ = (
        {
            "mysql_engine": "InnoDB",
            "mysql_charset": "utf8",
            "mysql_collate": "utf8_general_ci",
        },
    )

    id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column("name", db.String(45), nullable=False)


class Bld(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tb_bld"
    __bind_key__ = "testdb"
    __table_args__ = (
        {
            "mysql_engine": "InnoDB",
            "mysql_charset": "utf8",
            "mysql_collate": "utf8_general_ci",
        },
    )

    id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    name = db.Column("name", db.String(100), nullable=False)

    variant_id = db.Column(
        "variant_id",
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey(
            "tb_nv.id",
            name="fk_tb_bld_variant_id",
            onupdate="CASCADE",
            ondelete="RESTRICT",
        ),
        nullable=False,
    )

    variant = db.relationship("NV")


def display(values):
    """Display values in a decent way."""
    pprint.pprint(values)


def connect():
    """
    Connect to Staging for testing.

    This is based on https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/translating-sql-queries-to-sqlalchemy-orm-a8603085762b
    ...and ./game-publishing/services/api/deploy/celery/config/staging-base.j2
    """
    conn_str = "mysql://{}:{}@{}/{}".format(
        os.environ["DBU"],
        os.environ["DBP"],
        os.environ["DBH"],
        os.environ["IDB"],
    )
    engine = create_engine(conn_str)
    session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    sess = session()
    return (engine, sess)


def main():
    """A minimal query that exhibits the problem."""
    (engine, session) = connect()

    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    v = aliased(Vers, name="v")
    v_2 = aliased(Vers, name="v_2")
    nv_4 = aliased(NV, name="nv_4")
    bs = aliased(St, name="bs")
    bs_2 = aliased(St, name="bs_2")
    bs_3 = aliased(St, name="bs_3")
    br = aliased(Br, name="br")

    q1 = select(nv_4.id, func.min(bs_3.build_id)).select_from(bs, v)

    q2 = q1.join(v_2, onclause=(bs.version_id == v_2.id))
    q3 = q2.join(bs_2, onclause=(br.id == bs_2.branch_id))

    result = session.execute(q3)
    display(result.scalars().all())


main()
```

The exception I'm getting (in case you don't see the same result), is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't determine which FROM clause to join from, there are multiple FROMS which can join to this entity. Please use the .select_from() method to establish an explicit left side, as well as providing an explicit ON clause if not present already to help resolve the ambiguity.
```

I'm using:

```
$ python3 -m pip list -v | grep -i sqlalchemy
Flask-SQLAlchemy       2.5.1         /data/home/dstromberg/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages pip
SQLAlchemy             1.4.36        /data/home/dstromberg/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages pip

$ python3 -m pip list -v | grep -i mysql
mysqlclient            2.1.1         /data/home/dstromberg/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages pip
PyMySQL                0.8.0         /data/home/dstromberg/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages pip

bash-4.2# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.41, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

I've googled for hours, but I don't seem to be getting anywhere.  I found a few solutions to similar problems, but they didn't look similar enough to be useful.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: You do not share your models, it's unlikely we can accurately reproduce your problem without them. Please [edit] and add a propoper [minimal reproducible
example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I've added example models.  You're absolutely right that makes it easier to answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [select_from()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.select_from) method, try being more explicit, selecting from one table and then using the [join()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.join) method to build all the relationships.

Also, to help people answer, share the following:

1. Which version of Sqlalchemy are you using?
2. Which database? Some methods are DB-specific.
3. What does the query look like in SQL outside of SqlAlchemy?

I suggest trying something like this:

```
query = select(nv_4.id, func.min(bs_3.build_id))
.select_from(bs)
.join(v, bs.Relationship == v.Relationship)
 # The order here may need to be modified, but hard to tell without seeing the data.
.join(v_2, onclause=(bs.version_id == v_2.id))
.join(bs_2, onclause=(br.id == bs_2.branch_id))
```

Comment: I think I already shared the versions of SQLAlchemy and MySQL I'm using.  I didn't mention that we're using MySQL in production and SQLite3 in unit tests.  The version of SQLite3 is 3.34.1.  The actual SQL query is kind of big - I've stripped the SQL ORM code above quite a bit, to be a (much) easier thing to test with.

Comment: The code above gives: "AttributeError: type object 'St' has no attribute 'Relationship'".  Any suggestions for that?

Comment: If I comment out the bs.Relationship == v.Relationship line, I get: Unknown column 'br.id' in 'on clause'.  Any suggestions for that?

Comment: We were thinking we had a workaround if this wasn't working out, but now it's looking like we don't - at least, not that workaround.  So now this is pretty important for us.

Comment: I'm just running this without any data in it.

Comment: @dstromberg - my answer was to highlight a way to address the error you shared in the OP. The "bs.Relationship == v.Relationship" part was meant to convey that you need to build your relationships. "Relationship" is just a placeholder of whichever column name maps to both tables aliased as "bs" and "v". Hard to help more without seeing the tables + SQL.